# Pending "reverting to original state" Git message after commit failed due to failed tasks

Tags: git

After attempting to commit my work, Git reported failed tasks and the last thing stated is:

> "Reverting to original state... [started]"

And then nothing. I'm scared to abort as it might mess up my local repo or something.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: This is your `pre-commit` hook failing, the cause is arguably to search in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.